# How to set AlarmManager for two independent timebase

Tags: service, time, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I'm working on an app which will trigger a future event.  I set the AlarmManager to achieve this.  The code is general:

```
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pintent);
```

I would like to see how I can set multiple future events to the AlarmManager.  The times for future events are all independent, some may repetitive and some may one shot.

Any body has experience on this feature?  Would you mind sharing here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the `PendingIntent` that you pass to the `AlarmManager` is unique for each event. To make the `PendingIntent` unique you have some alternatives:

- Use a unique `requestCode` argument in the call to `PendingIntent.getService()`
- Use a unique ACTION in the `Intent` that you pass to `PendingIntent.getService()`
- Use unique DATA in the `Intent` that you pass to `PendingIntent.getService()`

Note: Using different EXTRAS in the `Intent` that you pass to `PendingIntent.getService()` **will not** make the `PendingIntent` unique!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks David.

I achieved that by using a unique requestCode.